# What is the difference between ' ' and " " in python?

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there any difference between “string” and 'string' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143714/is-there-any-difference-between-string-and-string-in-python)
>   [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

I have noted that I can use both single and double quotes to delimit strings in python, and that whichever one I *don't* use to delimit the string, I can use freely inside it without any need to escape it.

Examples:

```
ex1 = 'this works'
ex2 = "this works too"
ex3 = "it's much easier to write it's this way"
ex4 = 'but this way, it\'s possible to print out "quotes from other people"'
```

In other languages, however, I've seen cases both where it doesn't matter (in JavaScript, both `'hi'=="hi"` and `'hi'==="hi"` return `true`) and where it does (in C#, `"d"` is a `string` while `'d'` is a `char`)

Now, I'm wondering if there's really a difference "under the hood". Does python care which of `'` and `"` I use? If so, in what way?

Comment: I'm sorry if this has been asked before. The search engine won't take ' or ", and my searches for "python string char" and other similar queries returned no clarifying results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between "string" and 'string' in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143714/is-there-any-difference-between-string-and-string-in-python) (@Thomas: Found it through "python string quotes")

Comment: @Tomas: It has, see the link in delnan's comment above.

Comment: @Sven: Not quite, that question is "I know there's no difference, but when should I use which?".

Comment: You could use the string `python quotes` in search engine.

Comment: To really blow your mind check out `"""` and `'''`

Comment: @delnan: I just wanted the other link to be in the "possible duplicates" list above since I think it is useful (and the page certainly answers this question).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no difference at runtime. The only difference between the two types of quotes is the one you have already pointed out:

- Single quotes need to be escaped inside single quoted string literals but not inside double-quoted string literals.
- Double quotes need to be escaped inside double quoted string literals but not inside single-quoted string literals.

Note: If you use triple-quoted strings (`"""foo"""` or `'''bar'''`) then you dont need to escape either (unless you happen to have a sequence of three quotes in a row inside the string).

Comment: So if you need to print a string with quotes you can do 'my "easy" string' and if you need to print a single quote you can do "this ain't hard" - there is no need for any special escape sequence

Comment: 6 upvotes and no one bothered to even read the escape sequence part, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: I don't see the error.... could you enlighten us?