# What does """ mean in python?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

```
"""
something
"""
```

OR

```
'''
something else
'''
```

What does the `"""` mean? How is it used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643894/triple-double-quote-v-s-double-quote You'll find an answer here

Comment: This can be answered by reading the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=triple%20quoted%20strings#strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936231/3488550). There is no difference in other than punctuation which you use.